# Permission denied error after adding SSH Key to Digital Ocean

Tags: ssh, digital-ocean

I have a Windows machine that is working as expected but on my Mac OS X Sierra 10.13.5, I get this error `Permission denied (publickey)`

STEPS TAKEN TO START ANEW:

1. I deleted ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
2. I made a backup of ~/.ssh/known_hosts  (ran mv known_host
   known_hostBackup)  (then ran touch known_host). So, every thing should be clean and ready for new ssh key to be generated, I think...
3. Ran ssh-keygen
4. Ran cat id_rsa.pub and copied the new ssh key

`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDOZoANykFA4ta2ft4wSS9Hqsvi+b8r3XDaUlBSPRyPzwXXXXX≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈≈XXXXXaWfO3X9SEFtE7Qe8NxXjmkgC4BYZSg4QFRV2Is5PiUn5MXs4StmNzZGcj8kFQd4PG0go1FqAsixT myname@apples-mbp`

5. Went to Digital Ocean / Settings / Security / SSH Keys, created a new one and pasted the entire SSH key.

I still get the error 
`root@128.261.64.32: Permission denied (publickey)`

Is there a local setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the key used for root user or the root user may be disabled in sshd. Please refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQWRp-FdTpc&t=2351s) for details. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you K,

I missed the step of adding the authorized_keys to the server. This fixed it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-add-an-ssh-key-to-an-existing-droplet

cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"